# SQL grouping and limiting results per group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (that you can see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/009e8/1) with movies and each movie has a genre and the release date.

```
CREATE TABLE Movie (
    ID int,
    Title varchar(255),
    Genre varchar(255),
    Year int
);

INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 1', 'Horror', 1982);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 2', 'Drama', 1983);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 3', 'Horror', 1984);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 4', 'Comedy', 1985);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 5', 'Sci-Fi', 1986);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 6', 'Horror', 1987);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 7', 'Drama', 2010);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 8', 'Horror', 2008);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 9', 'Horror', 2006);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 10', 'Comedy', 2004);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 11', 'Horror', 2003);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 12', 'Drama', 2002);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 13', 'Comedy', 1999);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 14', 'Drama', 1967);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 15', 'Sci-Fi', 1982);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 16', 'Drama', 2009);
INSERT into Movie VALUES(1, 'Movie 17', 'Sci-Fi', 2008);
```

I want to able to get all the movies with a particular genre (`SELECT * FROM Movie WHERE Genre in ('Horror', 'Drama')`) but limiting the result *per genre* ordered by year

So, if I have 100 Drama movies, 100 Horror movies and 100 comedies, I want only the two oldest Drama and the two oldest Horror movies.

How to do this in Sql? If in standard SQL this is not possible, I'm using Postgres

Comment: I think it can be done using cte and rownumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (SELECT
  id,
  title,
  genre,
  year,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY genre ORDER BY year) AS year_calc
FROM Movie
WHERE Genre IN ('Horror', 'Drama')) a
WHERE year_calc IN (1, 2);
```

Saravanan

Answer (score 0):

As @Arijit Mukherjee suggested you can use `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *, seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Genre ORDER BY Year ASC)
  FROM Movie
  WHERE Genre in ('Horror', 'Drama')
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE seq <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rank_filter.* FROM (
    SELECT Movie.*, 
    rank() OVER (
        PARTITION BY Genre
        ORDER BY Year
    )
    FROM Movie
) rank_filter WHERE RANK IN (1,2)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/009e8/13